# I want to enable or say start WiFi tethering in android device by executing adb shell command

Tags: android, shell, hotspot, adb

I want to enable hotspot or say start WiFi tethering in android device by executing adb shell command.

What is the adb command used for it?

To turn on bluetooth - `adb shell am start -a android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE`.

To open wifi- `adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiSettings`.

But I can not find for turning on hotspot.

Comment: you can take a look at this [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/173709/how-to-turn-on-the-wi-fi-hotspot-using-adb). There is no fixed solution that works for all phones, you can setup the commands so that they works for most phones, on the other hand you could probably check the model and version and execute the commands as needed

Comment: Thanks casualcoder